# MYSQL Database Schema Question

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need opinions on the best way to go about creating a table or collection of tables to handle this unique problem. Basically, I'm designing this site with business profiles. The profile table contains all your usual things such as name, uniqueID, address, ect. Now, the whole idea of the site is that it's going to be collecting a small string of informative text. I want to allow the clients to be able to store one per date, with as many as 30 days in advance. The program is only going to show the information from the current date on forward, with expired dates not being shown.

The only way I can really see this being done is a table consisting of the uniqueID, date, and the informative block of text, but this creates pretty extensive queries. Eventually this table is going to be at least 20 times larger than the table of businesses in the first place as these businesses are going to be able to post up to 30 items in this table using their uniqueID.

Now, imagine the search page brings up a list of businesses in the area, it's then got to query the new table for all of those ids to get that block of information I want to show based on the date. I'm pretty sure it would be a rather intensive couple of queries just to show a rather simple block of text, but I imagine this is how status updates work for social networking sites in general? Does facebook store updates in a table of updates tied to a users ID number or have they come up with a better way?

I'm just trying to gain a little more insight into DB design, so throw out any ideas you might have.

Comment: Hi Jacob. 5 questions, 0 accepted answers. Please [read the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and learn how this community operates.

Comment: The question is too open. The queries are probably not that expensive anyway with the proper index on date, and (some kind of) area.

Comment: I don't want to guess what can be this "string of informative text", but most businesses won't enter 30 items on 30 days, so the table with informative texts will probably not be as large as you think.

Comment: First make it work; then measure, and optimize. It looks to me like premature optimization, rather than a design problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only way I can really see this being done is a table consisting of the uniqueID, date, and the informative block of text...

Assuming you mean the profile uniqueID, and not a unique ID for the text table, you're correct.

As pascal said in his comment, you'd need a primary index on uniqueID and date.  A person could only enter one row of text for a given date.

If you want to retrieve the next text row for a person, your SQL query would have the following clauses:

```
WHERE UNIQUE_ID = PROFILE.UNIQUE_ID
AND DATE >= CURRENT_DATE
LIMIT 1
```

Since you have an index on uniqueID and date, this should be a fast query.

If you want to retrieve the next 5 texts for a particular person, you'd just have to make one change:

```
WHERE UNIQUE_ID = PROFILE.UNIQUE_ID
AND DATE >= CURRENT_DATE
LIMIT 5
```